# Can't we pass obj data as prop to different components in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

So I want to pass data(object) as prop to different component. My goal to make the table component reusable.

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
import {onMount} from 'svelte';
import Tabel from './components/Tabel.svelte';
let data = [];
onMount(async () => {
  try {
   let res = await fetch(url); // your url
   data = await res.json();
  } catch(err){
   throw err;
  }
})
</script>

<Tabel {data} />
```

**Table.svelte**

```
<script>
export let data = [];
</script>
<table class="table-auto">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="px-4 py-2">Name</th>
      <th class="px-4 py-2">Age</th>
      <!-- and so on -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {#each data as {name, age}, i}
    <tr>
      <th class="px-4 py-2">{name}</th>
      <th class="px-4 py-2">{age}</th>
      <!-- and so on -->
    </tr>
  {/each}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But I've got an error like this:

```
rollup v2.16.1
bundles src/main.js → public/build/bundle.js...
[!] Error: Could not resolve './components/Tabel.svelte' from src/App.svelte
Error: Could not resolve './components/Tabel.svelte' from src/App.svelte
```

Comment: Add the paths of the two files. This is most probably a path issue (i.e. where the files are located).

Comment: I'm pretty sure my paths is correct

Comment: Never be pretty sure in programming.

Comment: My paths absolutely fine. Got another idea?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. Import Table by its proper name:

```
<script>
import Table from './components/Table.svelte';  // <- fix this

//...
</script>


<Table {data}/>
```

Comment: You meant I need to change Tabel name?

Comment: It's works. I don't know why Svelte doesn't allow to make name Table.svelte

Comment: The component file is named `Table.svelte`. Therefore you must import from `'./Table.svelte`. You may be able to import it as `Tabel` and use that as the element. This I don't know, but here, I'd stick to the correct spelling :)

Comment: You can call the imported component whatever you want — you can do `import Potato from './Table.svelte'` if you want. But the source string *obviously* has to correspond to the name of the actual file. Computers aren't just going to magically account for your typos!